# Why is the Edit breakpoints option missing from BIDS Control Flow tasks context menu?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ssis, breakpoints, bids

I have an existing SSIS project that I am trying to debug.

I can see the *Control Flow* tab correctly but there is no **`Edit breakpoints...`** option on the context menu, which appears when you right-click on *Control Flow* tasks such as *`Execute SQL Task`*, *`Script task`* etc.

Solution explorer does not have anything related to debugging either and only *`Deploy`* option is visible. Debugging from the main menu results in **`Canceled by user`** error almost immediately.

Would you know how this can possibly be the case and how to remedy it?

*`*.dtsx`* files are on a machine that I remotely connect to. I run Visual studio under another user and the server is on yet another machine. Could this possibly affect the contents of the context menus?

#### Environment information:

- Windows XP
- VS 2008 Pro
- BIDS
- MS SQL Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to the SQL Server 2012 release of SSIS, you cannot debug script components (those in a data flow). The general approach I've seen and used it to emit the information I want to use to debug via message boxes or throw information events and then log those out.

A script task (control flow) should provide you the ability to set breakpoints however you need them.

There's nothing to "debug" in an `Execute SQL Task`. You can breakpoint the usual stuff Pre/Post Execute but no way I'm aware of to debug into SQL Server from there.

The only other thought I have is that you might be just "opening" an SSIS package in Visual Studio/BIDS. While it allows you to view a package, you can't *do* anything with it unless the editor has an SSIS project opened.

Package without a project, notice greyed out Play button

[image]

Package edited within a project, green play arrow

[image]

Comment: I had a slution, but apparently it was screwed up. Creating a new one helped.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your error message **`Canceled by User`**, it could be due to the issue explained in the below Microsoft Knowledge Base (*`KB 2013735`*) article. KB states that the issue occurs only on *Windows Vista* and *Windows 7* but it does affect Visual Studio 2008 Professional. I am not entirely sure if this would help your case.

[*SQL Debugging Fails with “Canceled by user” message*](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2013735)

#### Quoted from KB 2013735:

Add Inbound port exception to the windows firewall for the following protocol/ports:

- *`TCP 135`*
- *`UDP 400`*
- *`UDP 500`*

Applies to:

- *Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition*
- *Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Standard Edition*

Comment: This is probably not my case, since I am on Win XP, but thank you for your help.